# Controller not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below code is not giving output as expected i:e Hello,World
output: {{ greetings.text }}, world

Can anyone help me why its not displaying 'hello, world' instead where I am wrong

```
<!doctype html>
    <html ng-app>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular JS App 1</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-v1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller='HelloController'> //controller
            <p>{{ greetings.text }}, World</p>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

script for controller

```
function HelloController($scope){
    $scope.greetings = {text : 'hello'};
}
```

Comment: Post you script please.

Comment: Post your controller definition

Comment: I think your ng-app is missing

Comment: added the script for controller

Answer (score 4):

Global controller isn't allowed from `1.3.x`

Try like this

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("HelloController", function($scope) {
    $scope.greetings = {
        text: 'hellow world'
    }
});
```

HTML

add module name

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

Comment: thanks I was learning from old book.any suggestion on where to learn angularjs

Answer (score 1):

add module name in ng-app..
like

```
<div ng-app='app'>
</div>
```

like this

```
<script>
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
      $scope.test ="hello world";
    }])
</script>
```

[plunker code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xgVekNyfDkS36VvvBAzJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the value for `ng-app` directive.

Like

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
```

and you should have the angular module `myapp` defined in script.